# Hover is not working when creating menu in CSS

Tags: hover, css

I'm using CSS for creating a dropdown menu, but I don't know what's going wrong with it. It's not dropping the sub-menu (un-ordered list in my code)
when hover is fired. I'm badly stuck here, please help me out.

I also tried the visibility property instead of display. I could see only
`menu1, menu2, menu3` in browser horizontally and nothing else.

I'm using IE7 on XP SP3.

#### CSS:

```css
#navMenu ul{
    argin:0;        
    padding:0;
}
#navMenu li {
    margin:px;    
    padding:0;  
    position:relative;
    float:left; 
    display:block;  
    list-style:none;
}
#navMenu li a{
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:100;  
    display:block;
}
#navMenu ul ul{ 
    display:none;
}
#navMenu ul li : hover  ul {
    width:auto;
    position:absolute;
    background:#453DD;
    display:block;
}
```

#### HTML:

```html
<div id="wrapper" >
    <div id="navMenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">menu1</a>  
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">menuitem11</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menuitem12</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menuitem13</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menuitem14</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">menu2</a>   
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">menuitem11</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menuitem12</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menuitem13</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menuitem14</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">menu3</a>   
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">menuitem11</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menuitem12</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menuitem13</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">menuitem14</a></li>
                </ul>   
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/G8j9n/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There mustn't any space between the tag name and pseudo class like you must use `li:hover` instead of `li : hover`.

Answer (score 1):

Your style has become messed up. It's missing units and/or values. This seems to work. You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7SMw8/).

```
#navMenu ul{
margin:0;        
padding:0;
}
#navMenu li {
margin:0px;    
padding:0;  
position:relative;
float:left; 
display:block;  
list-style:none;
}
#navMenu li a{
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
width:100px;  
display:block;
}
#navMenu ul ul{ 
display:none;
}
#navMenu ul li:hover  ul {
width:auto;
position:absolute;
background:#453DD;
display:block;
}
```